# How to configure angular cli to ignore unchanged chunk during recompile

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

When using 'ng serve' on this repo (https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app), angular cli [only recompile the changed chunk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9dCu.png). How can we achieve this ?

How can we configure a new app to behave the same if we are using angular cli to generate the app ? (ng new newApp)

Comment: Why do you think it's not already like that?

Comment: Silly me, just realised it's because the older version of angular cli (1.5) that I'm using does not have this feature yet